# Java suppressing java unknown publisher warnings in development environments

Tags: java, security, applet

The most recent version of the JRE plugin , JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18, when installed will cause the appearance of a Pop-up warning every time you download an applet.   [image]

We do sign our jars but in a development environment, but we do this using a generic certificate which makes us look like an Unknown publisher.   Yes you can register your domain by purchasing a certificate but this is not practical in a development environment.    In future releases of java, you will not even be able to click through the warning.   The applet simply will not load, according to oracle.
    http://www.java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml

As a developer, its not clear what to do in my development environments to be able to test and demonstrate my applets without being hindered by these security restrictions.   Any one have a solution?

Comment: Surely you want to know in a development environment that your applet isn't secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most recent version of the JRE plugin , JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18 ..

That has been happening since 1.7.0_21.

For individual development machines, you might adjust policy files (don't ask me how - I never user them) or tweak the Java Control Panel - Security tab settings.

OK judging by the descriptions below, only a policy file will do it, though you might look into <kbd>Manage Certificates...</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I see you changed your avatar. What is it?

Comment: @PaulVargas  Code point 9832 of Unciode - "Hot Springs". I figure it looks a lot like the top of the Java coffee cup logo while dispensing with the cup. I was going to make the round curve at bottom brown (coffee) and the wavy curves at the top red (hot), but in the end I could not be bothered. ;)